# How to pass a value to the bot using the ImBack type but witout showing the text on the chat window

Tags: botframework

I have defined a ThumbnailCard using this structure:

```
private static Attachment GetThumbnailCard()
{
  var thumbnailCard= new ThumbnailCard
  {
    Title = "title",
    Subtitle = "subtitle",
    Text = "text",
    Images = new List<CardImage>() { new CardImage(url: "http://example.com/image.jpg")},
    Buttons = new List<CardAction>() { new CardAction(type: ActionTypes.ImBack, title: "Product 1", value: "Product 01") },
  };

  return thumbnailCard.ToAttachment();
}
```

And everything is working fine, the button is showing "Product 1" and when the user uses the button you see on the chat window the content of value in this case "Product 01".

But i need more functionality, so i review the documentation and found other parameters of the `cardAction` class like `text` and `displayText`.

So that when the user uses the button on the chat you will see "I want to buy Product 01", and the bot will get the Id of that product so it can check it on the database.

I have done this according to the documentation:

```
new CardAction(type: ActionTypes.ImBack, title: "Product 1", value: "IdOfProduct01", text: "Product 01", displayText: "I Want to buy Product 01")
```

And i am receiving the value on this method:

```
private async Task ReceivingButtonClick(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
      var rpta = await result as Activity;
    }
```

But when i try to access `rpta.value` it is always null, and the chat windows is still showing the content of `value` instead of `displayText` or `text`

Does anyone knows if maybe this functionality is not available yet, i'm using Microsoft.Bot.Builder 3.13.1 and i am testing this on the emulator, or maybe i'm receiving the result as an Activity and i should be receiving it as something else.

Thanks in advance for the answers.

Comment: `ActionTypes.PostBack`

Answer (score 2):

This is the current behavior in BOT Framework. ImBack is similar to just typing a message and it sends back whatever was set in the 'value'. I guess you don't want to show id to the user when he/she clicks the product button. You can instead use *ActionTypes.PostBack* as type and that will send back the message to BOT but not show it on chat.

Try this:

```
new CardAction(type: ActionTypes.PostBack, title: "Product 1", value: "IdOfProduct01", text: "Product 01", displayText: "I Want to buy Product 01")
```

The problem with using PostBack is that it is not supported in all channels. So, make sure to check it for the channel you are implementing your bot for.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone knows if maybe this functionality is not available yet, i'm using Microsoft.Bot.Builder 3.13.1 and i am testing this on the emulator, or maybe i'm receiving the result as an Activity and i should be receiving it as something else.

The `displayText` and `Text` properties of `CardAction` were new added in v3 SDK, problem is that `DirectLineJS` hasn’t been modified to support these properties yet. You may refer to the source code of [directLine.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-DirectLineJS/blob/af5afc7e9dd4cb7ef5f50ae3ee9881f939556467/src/directLine.ts#L56) to see that problem.

And our emulator uses [WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) and `WebChat` uses `DirectLine`, so for `ActionTypes.ImBack`, that cause the problem.

You may submit an issue on [Github BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat), it will be convenient for us to monitor this issue. Thank you.